# Bitnami Magento Server for Mult-domain

Tags: apache, magento-1.9, bitnami

Have deployed a Bitnami Magento server a year back in GCP and it works fine for a year. Now planning to deploy additional website (different domain) to that same server as it has Apache and MySQL . Is there any suggested way to find information regarding to it. Just found that Bitnami large Wiki was been closed so none of wiki.bitnami.com links work .

Suggest steps or articles which explain about best way to make Bitnami Magento VM to multiple domain/multi website VM.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here,

Bitnami wiki has been moved to docs.bitnami.com. You could find more related information on https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/magento/#how-to-enable-multi-site-support.

I hope it helps